# CSS circle image with image offset

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create div with image inside with circle and image offset?
For example if I have an image with height 1200px and I want to create circle 100x100 pixels with CSS and this circle must have initial x position 500px?

Comment: So you want to scale the image with a height of 1200px to a circle of 100x100?

Comment: Ok. I have an image with 1200px 1200px and i want show circle from this image, but i want get this circle from fixed position, for example 500 by x and 200 by y

Comment: Okie - There goes my demo - take a look at it - has your specifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

CSS:

```
#circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid red;
    background-image: url('IMAGE-URL-HERE');
    background-position: 500px, 200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="circle"></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WFpYb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    .circleimg {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:purple;
background-position:500px 0;


    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="circleimg "></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tried execution of your question just refer it you can have with `100x100 pixels` and `initial x position 500px`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div
{
   border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
   padding:100px 100px; 
   background:#dddddd;
   width:300px;
   border-radius:500px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div> Circle image for Moldaone </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo with your positioning example, div background filled to the image's width and height and the size specified. [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/udiwox/1/)

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
   background-color: red; /*to show circle in demo */
   background-image: url("");
   background-size:contain;  
   /* contain scales image to largest size and makes it fit inside the content area. */
   background-position: 500px 200px;  
   border-radius: 50%;
   height: 1200px;
   width: 1200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive it with:

SCSS

```
  .rounded-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 2.5em;
    width: 2.5em;
  }
```

HTML

```
<img class="rounded-circle" 
    src="image-route" 
    alt="">
```

In my opinion, It's more elegant this way.